# Is HttpClient automatically secure by just using an HTTPS URI?

Tags: c#, https, tls1.2, dotnet-httpclient

I'm using the C# class `HttpClient` to make requests to a **RESTful API**. Are these requests secure by virtue of using an **HTTPS URI**? Or should I be doing more in the code to make sure the requests are secure?

Here is some sample code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.example.com");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("custom-header-1", "value-1");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("custom-header-2", "value-2");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue(type, credentials);
HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(URLParameters, content).Result;
return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

I've read some material online with conflicting ideas:

- Some people say that the URL being HTTPS is good enough.
- Others say you have to manually take care of certificates in the code.

I'm confused as to which school of though is correct.

Comment: If you use HTTPS then the transport is secure. It should be unreadable between the client and server. But security is a vague term. For instance, security could mean that you sanitize/validate the response before using it, especially if you reflect the data in a web UI.

Comment: @Crowcoder Sorry for being vague about what kind of security. I did mean transport. Thank you!